# c++: What does 'while (cin >> variable, variable)' exactly do?

Tags: c++, while-loop, comma-operator

So here's that piece of code, very basic but i just can't find any similar questions that have two variables in the while loop with cin in it.

```
void Perm(int start, int end, int a[]) {
  //some recursion code
}
int main() {
   int i, n, a[10];
   while (cin >> n, n) {
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
         a[i] = i + 1;
      }
      Perm(0, n, a);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Can't figure out what does while (cin >> n, n) part do, and when will it stops. It looks like when I run the code, the input is just required once..

Comment: That's actually an interesting one. Start reading here: [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)

Comment: This is the comma operator. The condition means "read ints until they aren't truthy anymore"

Comment: It reads from console and then (regardless of reading success) it evaluates `n` (false if it is zero). The intention was, probably, `while ( cin >> n && n )`, which means _"while you are able to read an integer and the integer is not zero"_.

Comment: Evaluate first expression.  Discard result.  Evaluate second expression.  In this case, if `cin >> n` fails, `n` will be set to `0` (C++17 or later), and the loop will exit.

Comment: `cin >> n && n` is equivalent to `cin >> n, n`. If `cin >> n` fails, [0 is written to n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: Thought the set to zero on failure was mandated in C++11. Now I have to go look that up.

Comment: Comments are assuming that the poster understands what `cin >> n` and `n` mean, and it's specifically the `,` that is confusing you.  Is this correct?

Comment: The comma operator evaluates its first operand, discards the result of that, and then gives the result of evaluating its second operand.   So the statement `while (cin >> n, n)` has the same net observable effect as `while (f(n))` where `f()` is defined as `int &f(int n) {cin >> n; return n;}`.   So your loop will stop when integer value of zero is entered (and, interestingly, will not stop if an error [like end of file] occurs while reading from the stream).

Answer (score 3):

The comma operator performs the expression to the left of the comma and discards the result then performs the expression on the right and offers up the result for testing. So, in English

```
while (cin >> n, n)
```

says, read from Standard In into integer `n` and discard whether or not the read was successful, then test the value of `n`. If `n` is not zero, enter the loop.

With a modern compiler the point is sort of moot, but I believe it would read better as

```
while (cin >> n && n)
```

or in English, if we successfully read from standard in into integer `n` and `n` is not zero, enter the loop. It conveys the intent better, but it's moot because if the read fails, as of C++11 `n` will be set to zero and still exit the loop. Before C++11 you probably got an infinite loop testing the last good, non-zero value of `n` over and over forever.

As explored in the comments below the point seems to be not so moot. It appears that under some conditions, [no data given in this case](https://godbolt.org/z/1safeb9rs), the value is **not** being zeroed. More Standard-reading required here, but it looks as though

```
while (cin >> n && n)
```

or similar [is required to catch all of the cases](https://godbolt.org/z/MxcvhGEWh).

Comment: "if the read fails, as of C++11 n will be set to zero"? I don't think that's right, is it? If the read fails, the variable is left untouched.

Comment: @paxdiablo Looking that up right now. It used to be left untouched, but I'm trying to find which standard changed the behaviour. When I find it, I'll get confirmation of the new behaviour as well.

Comment: g++ 9.4 in C++11 mode leaves it untouched.

Comment: @paxdiablo 17 is leaving it untouched as well. I'm running off of bad think, I think. Wonder where I picked it up.

Comment: Interesting, `./prog < /dev/null` leaves it untouched but `echo aa | ./prog` does not. So you're right that C++11 does zero it but not always? Likely a difference between no input and bad input.

Comment: [No input leaves it unchanged. Bad input zeros it.](https://godbolt.org/z/1safeb9rs) I need to do more digging.

Comment: The extraction operator is a serious rabbit hole, leading to character filtering, `strtoXX`, min/max checking, `get<int>()` calls and so on. Good luck with your journey :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo A rabbit hole I don't have time to follow all the way at the moment. cppreference says 0 on extraction failure and the min/max value if the input is out of range, but says absolutely nothing for the EOF case.

Comment: OK. That wasn't so bad: [\[istream.formatted.reqmts\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/istream.formatted.reqmts) *If `rdbuf()->sbumpc()` or `rdbuf()->sgetc()` returns `traits​::​eof()`, then `ios_­base​::​eofbit` is set in the local error state and the input function stops trying to obtain the requested input.* If I'm reading that right, it gives up before parsing  and reaching the code that'll change the value. C++11 doesn't have the same text, or at least not in the same place.

Comment: While it might "read better" (and also give some more error handling) `while (cin >> n && n)` is not equivalent to `while (cin >> n, n)`.   The latter doesn't check for (let alone handle) any errors on reading from the stream.

Answer (score 1):

In the condition of the while statement

```
while (cin >> n, n) {
```

there us used the comma operator.

That is the expression consists from two subexpressions, `cin >> n` and `n`, that are executed sequentially. The result of the condition is the value of the second subexpression that is implicitly converted to the type bool.

From the C++ 17 Standard (8.19 Comma operator)

> 1. ... A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded-value expression
>    (Clause 8). Every value computation and side effect associated with
>    the left expression is sequenced before every value computation and
>    side effect associated with the right expression. The type and value
>    of the result are the type and value of the right operand;...

The while loop can be equivalently rewritten like

```
while (cin >> n, n != 0 ) {
```

It would be more safer to write the condition of the while statement like

```
while (cin >> n, n != 0 && n <= 10 ) {
```

Instead of the comma operator it would be better to use the logical AND operator like for example

```
while (cin >> n && n != 0 && n <= 10 ) {
```

Comment: The importance of the `&& n <= 10` test cannot be stressed enough (prevents potential buffer overflow), but I'm not 100% sure it should be a loop exit condition

Answer (score 0):

That is a really nice and tricky question!

First, as pointed out in other answers, it performs a comma operator evaluation. Thus, the left operand (before the `,`) is evaluated and its side effects are committed, then it is discarded and the right operand (after the `,`) is evaluated and returned.

Note that, as pointed out in the comments, it is not the equivalent of `while (std::cin >> n && n)` because, in that one, it checks if it could do the input successfully. How is it done? When a error occurs (like if you pass a string instead of a integer, or you are reading from a file and an End-Of-File occurs), the `std::cin` returns a error that is converted to a `bool` and evaluated as `false` by any conditional statement.

You didn't initialize the variable `n`; this can cause UB (undefined behavior) because the C++ doesn't initialize variables automatically as some other languages do! What the program does is reserve a memory address for that variable and, if you don't explicitly initialize it, it will use any (garbage) value that is inside that memory address!

Let's simulate what could happen!

Let's read input from a empty file, initialize our variable, `n`, to any non-zero value then usie the comma operator in our while loop:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    freopen("test.txt", "r", stdin);
    int n=2502; 
    while (std::cin >> n, n)
    {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, `std::cin` will return EOF and the variable `n` will not be changed at all! Because the comma operator just returns the right operand, just the `n` will be checked in the while loop, and any non-zero int value is evaluated as `true`, so this will cause a infinite loop and will **always** print 2502 in the console.

If you change it to use `&&`, the `while` will check the `std::cin` as well, and EOF will be evaluated as `false` and the loop will never be executed.

P.S.: Note the uninitialized variables are UB, so it COULD work as expected on your machine and doesn't work in another machine, or it could work as expected in **your own machine** sometimes, and sometimes, suddenly, stop working as expected, making it HARD to debug.